# Searching popular sites in chrome from address bar not working

Tags: google-chrome, browser, search, microsoft-edge, address-bar

I recently reinstalled Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge. In both of these browsers I used to have a option to search popular sites like youtube/google maps/drive/superuser etc. in address bar.

What I mean is when I typed *youtube.com* in the address bar, the browsers prompted me to press`Tab` and when I did so, something like this appeared in the address bar:

```
Youtube | <Search term>
```

And from there it directly took me to the youtube.com results.

But now it doesn't work that way. The browsers don't show the prompts. And when I press `Tab` , it just highlights the last search suggestion.

Can anyone figure out whats wrong? I'm really missing the feature.

> - I mentioned both Chrome and Edge because they both are based on Chromium, and hence must have similiar solutions
> - I think only **Edge** supports searching ***superuser*** and ***stackoverflow***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have done a search on those sites for the suggestion to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to appear. So, go to youtube, or superuser. Use the search box and search for something. Then go to the address bar, while typing superuser, the suggestion should appear.

> I think only Edge supports searching superuser and stackoverflow

Chrome also supports searching superuser and stackoverflow.

Comment: Perfect! By the way I also found a way by going to `Manage Search Engines` in settings, however this is much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

#### To fix:

1. go to **chrome://settings/searchEngines** in [Chrome settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2P9X2.png)
2. **scroll down** to [**inactive sites**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8LcCW.png), you should see **youtube.com**
3. **Activate** it

> ##### If not present you can add it [Site Search section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1OVE.png)

After that when you type ***youtube.com*** in the **address bar**, the browsers will **prompt** you to **press** `Tab` it would **appear like this** in the address bar:

```
Youtube | <Search term>
```

And from there it directly take you to the **youtube.com results**.